# Google Cloud Pub/Sub › Load balancing pull request is not even between containers

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, containers, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently, I had a setup where I have two pods subscribes to the same subscription topic.
These two pods are running on Kubectl. I am publishing 20 messages to that topic. I am processing the messages in the batch of 5.

When I am making a pull request, my pull request load is not distributed between two containers. All 20 messages are either getting processed by one pod or another.
Process time of each message is just, 0.5sec so there is no problem in ACK'ing.

I am attaching the screen-shot.

[image] 
Could anyone let me know what is going on here? Why load is not getting distributed evenly?

Comment: 20 requests are not enough to scale. Try a few thousand requests.

Comment: thanks @John. I tried with 10K and it is working perfect.

Comment: my follow-up question is will it make sense if I have only 300-500 messages in PubSub and expecting the lower latency for the last ones? How can to deal with the situation?

Comment: I don't understand your comment "deal with the situation". However, I have not researched or had problems with Pub/Sub latency. If you have a specific issue with latency, you will need to open a support ticket with Google. Note that Pub/Sub is for decoupling systems and not for "instant" processing. Your design should not care if a message takes 10 micoseconds or 1000 milliseconds to arrive.

Comment: by 'deal with the situation' I mean to say that if there are two pods, processing the messages from PubSub for the same topic, how to distribute the load between pods?

Comment: You don't worry about distributing the load. Each pod will pull a message from the subscription. Once finished, each pod will pull another message. If this is a push subscription, the Pub/Sub will call an endpoint. Your internal systems (load balancer/ingress) will worry about which pod to forward the request to.

Comment: actually, my single message processing is taking around 4sec before it ACKs.  So, I tried with flow_control=50 to distribute the load but it didn't help.

Comment: You are not designing (or thinking about how this works) correctly. You do not care which pod (container) processes the Pub/Sub message. You only care that it is processed correctly. You should focus on how you scale your backend to handle whatever processing load is required. Not which item does the work.